# ctypes returns wrong value when -O optimizations used

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

C++ code that has a function `foo()` that has the external name `dll_foo()` which returns the value 10 when called.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo();

int main() {  
    cout << "Start" << endl;  
    return 0;
}

int foo() {
    return 10;
}

extern "C" {
    int dll_foo() {foo();}
}
```

This is compiled into a .dll for use with ctypes in this way (C++11 for an unrelated reason):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -static -shared main.cpp -o main.dll
```

Then called in python using LoadLibrary and I've tried setting restype too but that had no effect:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_uint

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("main.dll")
# lib.dll_foo.restype = c_uint
print(lib.dll_foo())
```

It prints a seemingly random number each time (16710260, 6224116, ...). The code does return the right value if no optimisation is used.

Comment: And where is the `return` statement for `dll_foo()`?

Comment: The compiler doesn't print a warning about not returning a value in `dll_foo`?

Comment: @eryksun Nope, is there a reason it works in the unoptimised versions?

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` to let g++ inform you of the mistake.

Comment: @eryksun Yes my mistake, should always use that to begin with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `int dll_foo() {return foo();}`. Without it the result is undefined indeed.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Any idea why it works in the unoptimised compiled versions?

Comment: @Lobstw I suppose in the unoptimized version `foo()` returns the value in the standard register `rax`, which `dll_foo` in turn doesn't modify.

Comment: @Lobstw: With optimization turned off, the compiler (probably) calls `foo`, which deposits its return value, then `dll_foo()` returns, with that value in the correct place for a return value. With the optimizer turned on, the compiler detects that you haven't (directly) used the value returned by `foo()`, so it eliminates the call to `foo()` completely.